# Building a 2D game for iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, sparrow-framework

What should I use to create a 2D game for iOS? There are a few alternatives, but I don't know what the performance implications are. I was considering OpenGL ES 2.0 and GLKit, Cocos 2D or just UIKit with Core Graphics.

Comment: cocos2d.  There is really no question about it, if you want to make games, learn cocos2d, building in UIKit can be successful, but its not the best approach, so don't waste the time :) (YMMV/IMHO)

Comment: Unless you provide more info about your game, we can't give you more specific answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL (GLKit, ES 2.0) will definitely have better performance, but requires more effort from your part. CoreGraphics is the easiest solution but may not be powerful enough for complex games. Cocos2D will give you decent performance (way better than CoreGraphics, but probably worse than OpenGL), and have intermediate difficulty and complexity. So:

- If the game is very simple and you want to finish it quickly, use CoreGraphics.
- If the game is complex and you want to finish it as quickly as possible, use Cocos2D.
- If the game is complex and you want to have complete control over how it works, use OpenGL. You will be able to make things that are not possible with the other two options but you will take much more time to learn OpenGL and to write the game.

Answer (score 2):

Cocos2d is quite powerful and will help you build an application faster, but it will hide much of the low-level details. OpenGL and UIKit graphics will give you a better understanding and control of things, but will take considerably more time to learn. Any one of these methods has very good tutorials around the net.

Comment: Yes, it is, and you can even mix OpenGL functions with cocos2d.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I have used the Sparrow Framework and I highly recommend it:  http://www.sparrow-framework.org

FULL DISCLOSURE:  I am a moderator and active member of the Sparrow community

Programming GL on your own can be a frightening task...and CoreGraphics is only suited for simple things.  Cocos2D has a good reputation as well, but for whatever reason I tried Sparrow instead.

Comment: I'd love to see a list of games built using the Sparrow Framework.

Comment: Your wish is my command ^^:  http://wiki.sparrow-framework.org/games/start

Shameless personal plug:  My sparrow-powered game is http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pandemic/id458587395?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add onto the other answer.

In addition to how much time you have to learn consideration and how easy of use of the engine, two of which are very important points for consideration, you should also look at what your game requires and which one of these choices would best suit your project.

If say your game deals with rigid body collision detection then, something like Sparrow Framework could certainly get you there with spherical collision algorithm but what if you were say to make a game like Worms with destructible environment.

You'd need to deal with pixel operations like erasing bitmask in a separate buffer. These are low level stuff which will likely require OpenGL ES.

Also, it would be wise to also check whether the project is still actively being developed.

So the choice comes down to:

1) time

2) ease of use

3) performance

4) out of the box features

5) is it still under active development